# Using While SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I have two tables and both contains columns `Names` and `ID_Number`.

- `table1` contains columns `Names`, `ID_Number`, `Price_date`
- `table2` contains columns `Names`, `ID_Number`, `historical_date`, `comments`

I am trying to do a loop such that it will start from the first value in `ID_Number` column in table1 and see if it matches with any value in `ID_number` column in `table2`.

If there is a match, then compare the 'Names' for the two tables for that particular `ID_number`. If the names does not matched, then in the `comments` column, enter the `Name` from table1 and enter the `Price_date` from table1 to `historical_date` in `table2`.

Comment: This is possible using while logic, but sounds like it could also be accomplished using SET based logic, which should be your preference. Here's a good link https://sqlpadawan.com/2013/05/02/the-meaning-of-set-based/

Comment: Yep, this sounds like a simple `UPDATE` and `JOIN`. Certainly a `WHILE` is the last route you should be using here. SQL is a set based language so use set based solutions; it performs awful at iterative ones (such as a `WHILE`) as it isn't designed to perform them efficiently. Changing your mind set to stop thinking programmatically when using SQL is a very important step to make as early as you can.

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: What happens when there are multiple matches?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use loops in SQL, as long as you can avoid them. SQL is a set-based language, that is not optimized for iterative processes.

From your explanation, it seems like you want an `update` statement with a `join`. This should do what you want:

```
update t2
set t2.comments = t1.names, t2.historical_date = t1.price_date
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 
    on  t1.id_number = t2.id_number 
    and t1.names <> t2.names
```

Comment: I strongly agree with avoiding loops "if you can avoid them".  To be sure and just to addf to @GMB 's recommendation, though, I'll also state that Loops, incremental Recursive CTEs, Recursive Functions, Scalar Functions, XML, and other forms of RBAR can be avoided almost all the time.